# Output Design of a layout is not exact what is set while developing the Layout

Tags: android, android-studio

I am trying to design a layout ( basically a splash screen ) which shows the App logo in almost middle of the screen and the company tagline under the logo on the start of the App. While working in Android Studio the design of layout looks like this. I positioned it 200dp downwards from the top.

As you can see, logo is right in the middle of the screen.
But when i run the app on my emulator the screen appears like this.The logo is not at the exact position where i wanted it.

I want my logo at the same relative position, no matter how big the screen size is.

Assume if logo is positioned  at 200dp at 1000dp long screen. i want it at 400dp position on a 2000dp screen size.

Simulator : 5.0.0    API-21   768 X 1280

What are the possible solutions ??

Following image contains both outputs.

[Follow this Link for the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o9Ly4.png)

Here is the XML code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f84343"
android:weightSum="1">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="100dp"
    android:id="@+id/AppIcon"
    android:src="@drawable/unnamed"
    android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/simpler_better_faster"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_below="@+id/AppIcon"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Add the relevant XML code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use a `<RelativeLayout>` to achieve that. Below is the code using a `<LinearLayout>`. The key here is `android:gravity="center"` in the `<LinearLayout>` element:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#f84343"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:gravity="center">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/AppIcon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:src="@drawable/unnamed"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/simpler_better_faster"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**[EDIT]**

> OP - But if i go on using more widgets to the screen i might need to
>   position them relative to each other. how to overcome that with
>   Relative layout

Well, technically you can still add more widgets in their required order. But, if you really want to use a `<RelativeLayout>`, you can use something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#f84343"
                android:gravity="center_vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/AppIcon"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/unnamed"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/AppIcon"
        android:text="@string/simpler_better_faster"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:textSize="20dp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That worked. But if i go on using more widgets to the screen i might need to position them relative to each other. how to overcome that with Relative layout ?

Comment: @AyanBansal Ok...both the above codes should be able to do that.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've mixed up some `RelativeLayout`/`LinearLayout` attributes.

If you want to use RelativeLayout remove and modify some attributes.

Something like this instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:background="#f84343">

  <ImageView
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="100dp"
      android:id="@+id/AppIcon"
      android:src="@drawable/unnamed"
      android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

    <TextView
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/simpler_better_faster"
      android:layout_below="@id/AppIcon"
      android:id="@+id/textView"
      android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
      android:textColor="#ffffff"
      android:textSize="20dp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simplify it all down into a TextView if you ask me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f84343" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:text="@string/simpler_better_faster"
        android:drawableTop="@drawable/arrow_right_fill_dark" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This gets rid of the ImageView all together, the change being the `drawableTop` attribute that provides a drawable, centered above the text.